# Some help to prove the series converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Can someone please correct my answer I am not sure about it
[image]

Comment: use $(a_n-\frac{1}{n})^2$

Answer (score 0):

You should start instead with

"Since $$
\left(a_n \color{red}-\frac1n\right)^2\geq0
$$..."

Comment: sorry my mistake i write it wrong so what about the other answer is correct

Comment: Now its correct

Comment: @user198367 Now, your answer is correct. Thanks.